# Saxon seems to be ignoring certain XSL calls in Spring MVC application, causes FOP exception

Tags: spring-mvc, xslt, xsl-fo, saxon, apache-fop

I'm getting an error while trying to transform my xml file using a formatting object in one of my service classes in my Spring MVC web application:

```
net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: org.apache.fop.fo.ValidationException: "fo:root" is missing child elements. Required content model: (layout-master-set, declarations?, bookmark-tree?, (page-sequence|fox:external-document)+) (See position 30:-1)
```

The Java code that is throwing the exception is used to convert an xml file to pdf following the rules outlined in my formatting object.  **Java code in question:**

```
FopFactory f = FopFactory.newInstance();
//Load the fop configuration file (for installing custom fonts)
DefaultConfigurationBuilder cfgBuilder = new DefaultConfigurationBuilder();
Configuration cfg = cfgBuilder.buildFromFile(new File("src/main/webapp/resources/fop-config.xml"));
f.setUserConfig(cfg);

FOUserAgent agent = f.newFOUserAgent();         

OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new File(resultFileName));
os = new BufferedOutputStream(os);

Fop fop = f.newFop(MimeConstants.MIME_PDF, agent, os);

//Load the formatting object
TransformerFactory fac = new net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl();
Transformer t = fac.newTransformer(new StreamSource(new File("src/main/webapp/resources/fo.xsl")));

File file = new File(fileName);
Source src = new StreamSource(file);
Result r = new SAXResult(fop.getDefaultHandler());

//Perform the transformation and close resources
t.transform(src, r);
os.close();
```

**And here is the part of my formatting object that FOP doesn't seem to like:**

```
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="letter-first"
            page-height="11in" page-width="8.5in" margin-top="0.25in">

            <fo:region-body margin-top="1.0in" margin-bottom="0.75in"
                margin-left="0.60in" margin-right="0.60in" />
            <fo:region-before extent="0.7in" />
            <fo:region-after extent="0.4in" />
        </fo:simple-page-master>

        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="letter-rest"
            page-height="11in" page-width="8.5in" margin-top="0.25in">

            <fo:region-body margin-top="0.5in" margin-bottom="0.75in"
                margin-left="0.60in" margin-right="0.60in" />
            <fo:region-after extent="0.4in" />
        </fo:simple-page-master>
        <fo:page-sequence-master master-name="letter">
            <fo:single-page-master-reference
                master-reference="letter-first" />
            <fo:repeatable-page-master-reference
                master-reference="letter-rest" />
        </fo:page-sequence-master>
    </fo:layout-master-set>

    <!-- Drop in the body -->
    <xsl:apply-templates />
</fo:root>
```

I know that the exception is trying to tell me that I'm missing my fo:page-sequence element.  However, this element is present in the template that I'm trying to apply in the root element.  **Immediately below the code above, I declare my template:**

```
<xsl:template match="template">
    <fo:page-sequence master-reference="letter"
```

Which contains the page-sequence element that FOP is complaining about.

I've tried this exact code on a regular Java Application, and it runs just fine with no exceptions.  However, when running it through a service class in my Spring MVC web application, it all of a sudden can't apply xsl templates, and I haven't slightest clue why.

It looks like Saxon is not correctly interpreting the  call in my web application, but it is able to do so in an offline Java application with exactly the same code.

Does anyone have any ideas?  Also, let me know if you need more information and I'll be happy to provide it.

**Edit:  Saxon and FOP dependencies:**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
        <artifactId>fop</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.avalon.framework</groupId>
                <artifactId>avalon-framework-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.avalon.framework</groupId>
                <artifactId>avalon-framework-impl</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.saxon</groupId>
        <artifactId>saxon</artifactId>
        <version>9.1.0.8</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be defining the namespace declaration of "fo" prior to using it? http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/quickstartguide.html

Comment: I do define it in my stylesheet tag.  The XSL-FO code that I posted was just the part that FOP was complaining about, but my entire fo.xsl file is pretty lengthy, and includes all required namespace declarations.

Comment: Sorry, no ideas. I'm afraid system problems involving multiple products interacting (FOP, Saxon, Spring) aren't very amenable to the StackOverflow process. It's unlikely to be possible to resolve this without first reproducing it, and creating a repro is likely to be tricky.

Comment: Well assuming the error message is correct then I would assume that the input you process when the error occurs has no element processed  by the template with `match="template"`. So somehow the element is missing, maybe because of a different input or solely a different namespace.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I don't think this is the case.  `<xsl:apply-templates />` should apply that specific template regardless of what the match pattern is, if I understand correctly.

Comment: @MichaelKay I was hoping I'd get a response from you :P The strange thing is that when running this same code on a standard Maven project, it works just fine.  Adding Spring to the mix, however, causes this to occur when the code is called from my controller.  Both projects have FOP and saxon as dependencies, and the only major difference between the two POM files are the dependencies for Spring and Jackson in my Spring project.

Comment: Sadly, my knowledge of Spring would fit on the back of a postage stamp.

Comment: `apply-templates` processes all child nodes with matching templates, it then depends on the existing child nodes and the existing templates which output is produced.

Comment: @MartinHonnen so wouldn't that template be applied then?  It is processed and applied in my non-spring project just fine.

Comment: If the template were applied, it would generate the `fo:page-sequence` result element and you would not get that error. At least as far as I can tell. So my guess is that the input file does not have a `template` child element for the context node (the root node?) where you do the `apply-templates`. That is where I would look first, whether you really process the same file in both projects. I don't know where debug output goes in Spring, in a Java console program I would simply use `<xsl:messages select="/"/>` to see the processed input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never updated this, but I figured out that the problem was that the input file actually didn't have the correct namespaces declared, as Martin suggested in the comments.  I thought I was using a particular input file when it turns out I was using a different one entirely.